# Geom_points plot in ggplot using colnames as.numeric x axis and variables as y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file like this,

```
POS 23  23.1 34 40
41  NA  1   NA  NA
43  NA  NA  NA  NA
53  NA  NA  NA  3
64  NA  NA  NA  NA
64  NA  NA  2   NA
65  NA  1   NA  NA
66  NA  NA  NA  3
81  NA  NA  NA  NA
92  NA  NA  NA  5
94  NA  NA  NA  NA
94  NA  5   NA  NA
```

I need to plot this with R, having values from `20` to `40` `(colnames)` as `x` axis `continuous scale`, and as `y` axis I need to plot numbers `1` to `5` as `continuous scale` again and corresponding `geom_points.`
This is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
ggplot(melt(df), aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_point(size = 1, color = "blue") +
  xlab("age") +
  ylab("freq") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20, 40), breaks=c(20, 25, 30, 35, 40)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 5)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.7), angle=90))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you `melt(df)` without specifying which column is the ID column:

```
head(melt(df))
Using 23 as id variables
   23 variable value
1  NA      POS    41
2  NA      POS    43
3  NA      POS    53
4  NA      POS    64
5  NA      POS    64
6  NA      POS    65
```

If you are intent on using `melt()`, then specify `id.vars`.

```
head(melt(df, id.vars = "POS"))  
   POS variable value
1   41       23    NA
2   43       23    NA
3   53       23    NA
4   64       23    NA
5   64       23    NA
6   65       23    NA
```

I personally prefer `pivot_longer()` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(2:5) %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(name)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
    geom_point(size = 1, color = "blue") +
    xlab("age") +
    ylab("freq") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20, 40), breaks=c(20, 25, 30, 35, 40)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 5)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.7), angle=90))
```

[image]

Comment: pivot_longer(2:5) are the columns?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually now have the melt as in your second example, but may be my varibale and value are not numbers, the plot is really weird... How can I transform them in numeric?

Comment: @user3224522 - In the `pivot_longer` example, I have a step using `mutate` from `dplyr` to convert the `name` column to numeric. You can do a similar thing with your data.